# telephone no, email, address detection without hyperlink style in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am accessing my own webpage using UIWebView and in the xib file I checked phone numbers, links and addresses checkboxes under detection tab. the detection is working. But it appears in blue color with underline and I dont want these and apply my own custom style. Can someone drop me the code or your comments? Thanks

Comment: @rckoenes please correct spelling for Stack :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a css style. Something like:

```
 <html><head><style type=text/css> a {color:#FFF;} </style></head>...</html>
```